# How to amend (e.g. add/remove) the values of a ttk.Treeview tag (tkinter)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

How do I amend (e.g. add/remove) the values of the option `tags` in a `ttk.Treeview`? Is there any built in tkinter/widget methods that I can use?

```
...
columns = list(range(1,3))
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=columns)

tree.insert('', 'end', iid=1, values=(1,1), tags='1')
...
```

1. How do I add the value "NEWTAG" to `tags='1'`? `tags` should have the values '1' & "NEWTAG".
2. How do I add the replace '1' with "NEWTAG"? `tags` value should finally be "NEWTAG".
3. If the value of `tags` is already "1' and "NEWTAG", how do I remove "NEWTAG" so that `tags="1"?`

Comment: Have you looked at `tag_has` that IIRC returns list of iid and then you can just use those iid to remove values

Comment: What do you mean by "value" in: "_How do I add the value "NEWTAG" to...._". Are you confused between `tags` and `iid`

Comment: Maybe you can refer http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm#M59, like `root.tk.call(tree, 'tag', 'add', 'NEWTAG', '1') `, or `root.tk.call(tree, 'tag', 'remove', 'NEWTAG, '1')`.

Comment: @CoolCloud According to [documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Treeview.html), it says this about the .insert() method's `tags` option, _"You may supply one or more tag strings to be associated with this item. The value may be either a single string or a sequence of strings."_

Comment: I do not understand what you want, can you give a practical example as well

Comment: @JasonYang Thanks for the info. Will try it. I looked through `/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/ttk.py` but could not find such a method.

Comment: It is an internal tk command that can be executed with `call`

Comment: And why do you assume I downvoted your question...?

Comment: @CoolCloud Your reply came after my question. I misunderstood. Apologies. ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the [tcl documentation](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm#M59), a `ttk.Treeview` widget does have commands to add and remove a tag from a node or a list of nodes. However, these methods are not provided in the official tkinter wrapper; see the `Treeview` class in /usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/ttk.py.

Building on the comment by @JasonYang and answer by @CoolCloud, the test code below illustrates how to implement a wrapper to access the `tag add` and `tag remove` commands of the `ttk.Treeview` widget. Hopes this example can benefit tkinter users.

**Test Code:**  Please see the section on `# Methods to add and remove tag(s)`. For an explanation on why the `._w` attribute of a widget is used, please read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70047494/5722359).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self._create_treeview()
        self._test_tag_add_method()
        self._test_tag_remove_method()

    def _create_treeview(self):
        # Create Treeview
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, column=('A', 'B'), selectmode='none',
                                 height=7)
        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        # Setup column heading
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='Point', anchor='center')
        self.tree.heading('#1', text='x', anchor='center')
        self.tree.heading('#2', text='y', anchor='center')
        # #0, #01, #02 denotes the 0, 1st, 2nd columns

        # Setup column
        self.tree.column('#0', anchor='center', width=50)
        self.tree.column('#1', anchor='center', width=30)
        self.tree.column('#2', anchor='center', width=30)

        # Insert nodes
        data = [(10, 20), (30, 40), (50, 60)]
        for n, d in enumerate(data):
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', iid='n'+str(n), text=str(n), value=d,
                             tag='Current')
        node = 'n5 xxx'
        self.tree.insert('', 'end', iid=node, text=node, value=d, tag='Current')
        print(f"Nodes with 'Current' tag: {self.tree.tag_has('Current')}")

    def _test_tag_add_method(self):
        # Add 'House' to tag of node 'n1'
        tag = 'House'
        self.tag_add(tag, items='n1')  # works but incorrect type for items
        print(f"Nodes with 'House' tag: {self.tree.tag_has(tag)}")
        self.tag_add(tag, items=['n5 xxx'])  # Correct way of submitting items
        print(f"Nodes with 'House' tag: {self.tree.tag_has(tag)}")

        # Add 'NEWTAG' to tag of all nodes
        tag = 'NEWTAG'
        self.tag_add(tag, items=self.tree.get_children())
        print(f"Nodes with 'NEWTAG' tag: {self.tree.tag_has(tag)}")

    def _test_tag_remove_method(self):
        # Remove 'House' to tag of node 'n1'
        tag = 'House'
        self.tag_remove(tag, items='n1')  # works but incorrect type for items
        print(f"Nodes with 'House' tag: {self.tree.tag_has(tag)}")
        self.tag_remove(tag, items=['n5 xxx'])  # Correct way of submitting items
        print(f"Nodes with 'House' tag: {self.tree.tag_has(tag)}")

        # Add 'NEWTAG' to tag of all nodes
        tag = 'NEWTAG'
        self.tag_remove(tag, items=self.tree.get_children())
        print(f"Nodes with 'NEWTAG' tag: {self.tree.tag_has(tag)}")

    ###########################################################################
    # Methods to add and remove tag(s)
    ###########################################################################
    def tag_add(self, tag, items=None):
        '''Adds the specified tag to each of the listed items. If tag is
        already present for a particular item, then the tags for that item are
        unchanged. Note: items refers to the iid of the tree nodes and must be
        a list object.
        '''
        if items is None:
            self.tk.call(self.tree._w, 'tag', 'add', tag)
        else:
            self.tk.call(self.tree._w, 'tag', 'add', tag, items)

    def tag_remove(self, tag, items=None):
        '''Removes the specified tag from each of the listed items. If items is
        omitted, removes tag from each item in the tree. If tag is not present
        for a particular item, then the tags for that item are unchanged.
        Note: items refers to the iid of the tree nodes and must be a list
        object.
        '''
        if items is None:
            self.tk.call(self.tree._w, 'tag', 'remove', tag)
        else:
            self.tk.call(self.tree._w, 'tag', 'remove', tag, items)
    ###########################################################################


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.mainloop()
```

**Remark:** In both `tag add` and `tag remove` methods, the `items` argument must be a list object and not a string object. The element of the `items` argument must be a string object. In the event a string object with white space is passed in as `items`, a [_tkinter.TclError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70048772/5722359) would occur.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is to call some internet tcl widget commands(as mentioned in the comments) that `tkinter` does not provide. To do this, we use `tk.call` method. I have created two functions and manually assigned those functions to the `Treeview` object:

```
def add_tag(new_tag,iid):
    root.tk.call(tree,'tag','add',new_tag,iid)

def replace_tag(new_tag,to_be_replaced,iid=''):
    """If iid is ommited, replaces the old_tag from all the items if it exists"""

    if iid:
        root.tk.call(tree,'tag','add',new_tag,iid)
        root.tk.call(tree,'tag','remove',to_be_replaced,iid)    
    else:
        iids = tree.tag_has(to_be_replaced)
        root.tk.call(tree,'tag','remove',to_be_replaced)
        for i in iids:
            root.tk.call(tree,'tag','add',new_tag,i)

def delete_tag(tag_to_delete,iid=''):
    """If iid is ommited, deletes all the tag from all items"""

    if iid:
        root.tk.call(tree,'tag','remove',tag_to_delete,iid)
    else:
        root.tk.call(tree,'tag','remove',tag_to_delete)

tree.add_tag = add_tag
tree.replace_tag = replace_tag
tree.delete_tag = delete_tag

iids = tree.tag_has('OLDTAG')

# Adding a tag to the first item in the treeview
tree.add_tag('NEWTAG',iids[0]) # Choosing the first item
all_tags = tree.item(iids[0],'tags')
print(f'All tag for the given iid: {all_tags}') # ('OLDTAG', 'NEWTAG')

# Replacing the OLDTAG for all items
tree.replace_tag('OLDEST','OLDTAG')
all_tags = tree.item(iids[0],'tags')
print(f'All tag for the given iid: {all_tags}') # ('NEWTAG', 'OLDEST')

# Delete NEWTAG for the first item
tree.delete_tag('NEWTAG',iids[0])
all_tags = tree.item(iids[0],'tags')
print(f'All tag for the given iid: {all_tags}') # ('OLDEST',)
```

Though it would be much better to create your own class that does this. Do note that 'OLDTAG' is whatever tag you have given to the items pre-hand. It is not fully foolproof, so feel free to play around.

Entire code without any event driven prooceedures:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(root,columns=('No.','Name'),show='headings')
tree.pack()

def add_tag(new_tag,iid):
    root.tk.call(tree,'tag','add',new_tag,iid)

def replace_tag(new_tag,to_be_replaced,iid=''):
    """If iid is not specified replaces the old_tag from all the items if it exists"""

    if iid:
        root.tk.call(tree,'tag','add',new_tag,iid)
        root.tk.call(tree,'tag','remove',to_be_replaced,iid)    
    else:
        iids = tree.tag_has(to_be_replaced)
        root.tk.call(tree,'tag','remove',to_be_replaced)
        for i in iids:
            root.tk.call(tree,'tag','add',new_tag,i)

def delete_tag(tag_to_delete,iid=''):
    """If iid is ommited, deletes all the tag from all items"""

    if iid:
        root.tk.call(tree,'tag','remove',tag_to_delete,iid)
    else:
        root.tk.call(tree,'tag','remove',tag_to_delete)

lst = [[1,'Me'],[2,'Myself'],[3,'I']]

for i in ('No.','Name'):
    tree.heading(i,text=i)
    tree.column(i,width=100)

for i in lst:
    tree.insert('','end',values=i,tags='OLDTAG')

iids = tree.tag_has('OLDTAG')

tree.add_tag = add_tag
tree.replace_tag = replace_tag
tree.delete_tag = delete_tag

# Adding a tag to the first item in the treeview
tree.add_tag('NEWTAG',iids[0]) # Choosing the first item
all_tags = tree.item(iids[0],'tags')
print(f'All tag for the given iid: {all_tags}') # ('OLDTAG', 'NEWTAG')

# Replacing the OLDTAG for all items
tree.replace_tag('OLDEST','OLDTAG')
all_tags = tree.item(iids[0],'tags')
print(f'All tag for the given iid: {all_tags}') # ('NEWTAG', 'OLDEST')

# Delete NEWTAG for the first item
tree.delete_tag('NEWTAG',iids[0])
all_tags = tree.item(iids[0],'tags')
print(f'All tag for the given iid: {all_tags}') # ('OLDEST',)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I discovered from source code that `tk.call()` can be called directly from a widget. So rather then writing it as  `root.tk.call()` you can write it as `tree.tk.call()`. This is more convenient to do especially when writing a tkinter widget as a class object.

Comment: According to [tcl](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm#M59), the command to add tag is `pathName tag add tag items` In tkinter, this tcl command can be activated by `widget.tk.call(widget, 'tag', 'add', new_tag, node_iids)`.  The arguments `'tag', 'add', new_tag, node_iids` in the `tk.call()` method is the equivalent of  `pathName tag add tag items` in the tcl command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Appreciate. I have added 2 comments to help other tkinter users understand how to use the `tk.call()` method based on what I had learned from your answer.