# tkinter: Why is "self._w" used to refer to a widget and not "self" in the "tk.call" method?

Tags: python, tkinter

Below is a `tkinter.ttk` class extracted from `/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/ttk.py`. I noticed that in the line of code `self.tk.call(self._w, "set", value)`, `self._w` is used and not `self`. This happens throughout the source code `ttk.py`. May I know why this is done?

```
class Spinbox(Entry):
    """Ttk Spinbox is an Entry with increment and decrement arrows

    It is commonly used for number entry or to select from a list of
    string values.
    """

    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        """Construct a Ttk Spinbox widget with the parent master.

        STANDARD OPTIONS

            class, cursor, style, takefocus, validate,
            validatecommand, xscrollcommand, invalidcommand

        WIDGET-SPECIFIC OPTIONS

            to, from_, increment, values, wrap, format, command
        """
        Entry.__init__(self, master, "ttk::spinbox", **kw)


    def set(self, value):
        """Sets the value of the Spinbox to value."""
        self.tk.call(self._w, "set", value)
```

Comment: `self._w` store the name of the widget, so it is used in `tk.call()`.  However you can use `self` as well *whenever `self` is used as a string* because `Misc.__str__()` (all widgets inherit from it) returns `self._w`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every widget represents an object in an embedded tcl interpreter. These objects  have a unique name (eg: .frame.another_frame.some_button). This name is a string.

This widget name is also a command in the tcl interpreter. So, in order to call the underlying widget command, you must use the string name. `self._w` contains the string. Directly using `self._w` rather than converting `self` to a string is the most efficient way to do it.