# An issue with the "tag add" command of the ttk.Treeview widget - can't handle white space

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have noticed an issue with using the `tag add` command of a `ttk.Treeview` widget when activated with the `tk.call()` method. That is, **it can't handle white space in the value of the `str()` elements of its `items` argument.**

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70047143/5722359) on how I had implemented the tag add command. Now if `/home/user/Desktop/Secret Source` is passed in to items, the returned error msg is:

```
self.tk.call(self.tree._w, 'tag', 'add', tag, items)
_tkinter.TclError: Item /home/user/Desktop/Secret not found
```

The text  `Source` with one white space is missing from `Secret Source`. How do I overcome this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The treeview `tag add` command requires `items` to be a list, but you're passing a string. When tcl is given a string when it expects a list, the string will be split on whitespace to create a list. That is why it thinks the characters before the space is the whole item id.